# How to show the name from a text box?

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a guess word.
In the first form I have 2 text boxes for the players name:
[Player 1 and player 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hd51y.png)

So next I wanted the name of player 1 would be showed on the form, The name that he wrote.

[Player name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESgb7.png)

Thanks for the help ! :D

Comment: What have you tried so far. Where is your code?

Comment: Do something like this and use it later where you want:
Dim str as String
str = Textbox1.Text;

Comment: @Mike_Jr you missed the tag. its vb.net: Dim word = TextBox1.Text

Answer (score 0):

I did it :D

I created a class with this:
Public Shared savedname As String = Nothing

In the Textbox1 i used the code:
Class1.savedname = TextBox1.Text

And on the load of the the form that I wanted to show the name i code:
Label1.Text = Class1.savedname

Thanks!